# Inject bean from a different folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

I have a project structure that looks like this:

[image]

In My Groovy folder contains a class marked with `@Component` that I Want to inject in another class inside the java folder. However spring can't find the bean to inject, when I move the class marked with `@Component` to the java folder it works fine. How can I make spring aware of the groovy folder?

Comment: Spring is already aware of your folder as it is part of the classpath. If it cannot be found there is something wrong in your classpath setup. Also does it really fail at startup or is your IDE complaining (ignore the latter I would say).

Comment: It was actually spring complaining that it can't find the bean to inject it. However when I used the exact same package name in the groovy folder as the java folder, spring scanned that package for beans and found my class

Comment: But that is something you haven't told us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use @ComponentScan at your Spring application (annotated with @SpringBootApplication) to scan components from other packages.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.stackoverflow.other.package")
```

See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning.